# Как прочитать файл .txt с помощью pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, ipython

Мне нужно получить данные из файла "series matrix file(s)", который находится [тут](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE7670), но возникают ошибки при его считывании с помощью read_csv. Помогите разобраться.

Вот ошибки:

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CParserError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-29-6d3982f93f22> in <module>()
    ----> 1 pd.read_csv("GSE7670_series_matrix.txt")
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
        560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
        561 
    --> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
        563 
        564     parser_f.__name__ = name
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
        323         return parser
        324 
    --> 325     return parser.read()
        326 
        327 _parser_defaults = {
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
        813                 raise ValueError('skip_footer not supported for iteration')
        814 
    --> 815         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
        816 
        817         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):
    
    /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
       1312     def read(self, nrows=None):
       1313         try:
    -> 1314             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
       1315         except StopIteration:
       1316             if self._first_chunk:
    
    pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:8748)()
    
    pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/parser.c:9003)()
    
    pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/parser.c:9731)()
    
    pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/parser.c:9602)()
    
    pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas/parser.c:23325)()
    
    CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я думаю, вы не совсем правильно читаете этот файл.

`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 10`

говорит о том, что Pandas увидел 10 полей в строке 7, а ожидал увидеть только одно поле.

попробуйте следующее:

```
fn = r'/path/to/file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fn, skiprows=70, sep='\s*')
```

PS у меня нет доступа к вашему файлу, поэтому я протестировал мое решение на [этом](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269670937_GSE5147_series_matrixtxt) файле, в котором первые 70 строк являются описанием.  Поменяйте 70 на число строк описания в **вашем** файле

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.